# I need help using WHERE, CASE and BETWEEN together in SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause, case, between

With the help of google I have gotten the where statement to look like below but the program I am using says it is wrong without telling me what is wrong, and before anyone asks why I am doing what I am doing, the client wants the option to set both ends of the date range to the same date and have it populate with that dates info and just using WHERE BETWEEN was not working with that.

```
WHERE Date = Case WHEN @Y1=@Y2 THEN = @Y1 ELSE BETWEEN @Y1 AND @Y2 END
```

Any help is appreciated.

I have also tried adding additional where clauses such as `(where between y1 and y2 OR date=Y1 or date=Y2)` but that didn't seem to work ether.

Comment: No, you cannot have both an `=` and `between` in the same comparison like that. But nothing stops you from only using the `between`, which results in the equality when both ends are equal.

Comment: Can you add some examples? e.g. some dates and comparators, and whether you want the where statement to evaluate as true or not for each case?

Comment: as per my post "and just using WHERE BETWEEN was not working with that."

Comment: add table schema and data samples so we can reproduce

Comment: I would but I don't know what from the other 3 paragraphs of code you would need when the where clause is all that isn't working.

Comment: *as per my post "and just using WHERE BETWEEN was not working with that."* You should use `where date between`

Comment: `WHERE Date BETWEEN SYMMETRIC @Y1 AND @Y2` is all you need.

Comment: You should avoid the use of between entirely and use a proper range, especially when using dates and especially especially if the datatype is a date-time

Comment: As has been shown, it suffices to apply `WHERE Date BETWEEN @Y1 AND @Y2`. For other situations where you want different conditions depending on the parameters, just use `AND` and `OR`. E.g.: `WHERE (@Y1 = @Y2 AND Date = @Y1) OR (@Y1 <> @Y2 AND Date BETWEEN @Y1 AND @Y2)`. As a rule of thumb: `CASE WHEN` does not belong in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Your approach `where [date] between y1 and y2 OR date=Y1 or date=Y2` seems to indicate that you mistake what `BETWEEN` in SQL means exactly. According to [macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/between) "between" in English includes the stated values (e.g. "children between 5 and 7" means children aged 5, 6 or 7). I don't know, whether this is always the case in English, but in SQL it is. `BETWEEN 5 AND 7` means "from 5 to 7" (i.e. including the values).

Comment: `case` **expression** is an expression. It **should be able** to evaluate to some **value**. `= smth` is not a value as well as `between ... and ...`. You need to use boolean predicates combined with `AND/OR` instead of `case` expression because it's quite pointless to evaluate booleans via `case` instead of boolean operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, as it seems: you don't have to. A `BETWEEN` predicate on two equal values returns the same TRUE/FALSE answer as an equi predicate on the same value once:
See this test:

```
WITH
indata(dt) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2023-04-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-04-02'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-04-03'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-04-04'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-04-05'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-04-06'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-04-07'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-04-08'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-04-09'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-04-10'
)
,
srch(fromdt,todt,descr) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2023-04-01',DATE '2023-04-04','range'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-04-05',DATE '2023-04-05','equal'
)
SELECT
  dt, descr
FROM indata CROSS JOIN srch
WHERE dt BETWEEN fromdt AND todt
ORDER BY descr,dt;
-- out      dt     | descr 
-- out ------------+-------
-- out  2023-04-05 | equal
-- out  2023-04-01 | range
-- out  2023-04-02 | range
-- out  2023-04-03 | range
-- out  2023-04-04 | range
```

Do I need to comment the test or is it self explanatory?

Comment: it is self explanatory, thank you. that should be all I need to get the client to leave off the IN BETWEEN and let me find the actual problem.